How to prompt creation of one worksheet per column (VBA or otherwise)
I have been searching high and low for this answer. If I knew VBA better I would probably have this figured out by now. Everything I am finding when I search for the title is creating creation by ROW rather than column, or does columns but is basing it off the criteria IN the column rather than just the entire range (or mostly answers my question but I don't know how to adapt it to what I need).
I have a list of customer 190k customer IDs. I split them up into 191 columns of 999 (via the index formula) and each have the same data header (customer_id), plus a unique title that I want the new sheets to be labeled (so I can then save them as their own workbook, which I already have working VBA code for).
Tldr, I need to make each column below (which are on one sheet) in its own sheet, including header, with the sheet labeled "Column A"(or B, C, anything).
Here's a very basic visual example (if it will format correctly) of what I have on one sheet:



Column A
Column B




customer_id
customer_id


Cell 1
Cell 3


Cell 2
Cell 4



I know VBA well enough to be certain there is a way to do this (it's objectively pretty simple), but I DON'T know VBA well enough to actually write this out, or to really understand results from other people's questions and how to modify it for what I need. The more I search around, the more baffled I get. Any help is greatly appreciated, I know there are VBA experts out there that this would take 5 minutes for!

Could you share the code you got that saves each workbook?

The following should be a good template for you to expand on:
    Sub SplitColumnsToSheets()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim newWs As Worksheet
        Dim lastCol As Long
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim col As Long
        Dim colHeader As String
        Dim colRange As Range
        
        ' Set the worksheet where your columns are
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change Sheet1 to your sheet's name
        
        ' Find the last column in the sheet
        lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        ' Loop through each column
        For col = 1 To lastCol
            ' Get the column header
            colHeader = ws.Cells(1, col).Value
            
            ' Create a new sheet and name it based on the column header
            Set newWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            newWs.Name = colHeader
    
            
            ' Find the last row in this column
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
            
            ' Copy the column with the header to the new sheet
            Set colRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, col), ws.Cells(lastRow, col))
            colRange.Copy newWs.Range("A1")
        Next col
    End Sub



In this example the Columns values to added to new worksheets:
Sub Example()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet, newWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim Col As Range
    
    For Each Col In ws.UsedRange.Columns
        Set newWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        newWorksheet.Range("A1").Resize(Col.Cells.Count).Value = Col.Cells.Value
        newWorksheet.Name = Col.Cells(1, 1)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

